# how to describe cloudformation cross account stack info/name/details

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We've 2 aws accounts.Now we trying to migrate our prod environment resources to another aws account. We've set up pipeline in account A which will deploy resources in account B.
Our AWS infra stack is already available in account B and while running below cmd from account A we're getting below error:-

**cmd:- aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name prod-gateway**

**Error:- An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id prod-gateway does not exist**

which is a valid error because we're trying to fetch the account B stack info from account A and the stack is not exist in acc A.

**So the question is can I describe the stack info of account B from account A ? is there any cross account cmd to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is can I describe the stack info of account B from account A ? is there any cross account cmd to achieve this ?

You use for that [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) roles which you have to setup. In a nutshell:

- in accB you create a role which allows describing its stacks. The **trust relationship** of the role allows accA to assume the role.
- in accA you use [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) to assume the role from accB. This will give you new **temporary AWS credentials**. The IAM role/user in accB must have permissions to assume the role.
- in accA, using the temporary credentials, you can execute your `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` against accB.

Comment: thanks Marcin for your reply. in my cross-acc-B role I've already configured the trust relationship for codepipeline/codebuild/accA and this role has all the permission of s3,ecr,cloudfoamtion,kms,codebuild.

in accA codebuild/codepipeline role assume-role is configured but how can I generate this temporary AWS credentials ?

Comment: @PareshSahoo Not sure which `codepipeline/codebuild/accA`? Your question does not provide any details nor even mentions these services. If its new issue, I would recommend making new question.